# OneToMany Hibernate Failed To Save

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I have problem with OneToMany saving problem using hibernate.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lecturer")
public class LecturerEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 446089492592652000L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name="lecturer_name")
    private String lecturerName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    private DepartmentEntity department;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Department")
public class DepartmentEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6221599323765325196L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name="department_name")
    private String departmentName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="department")
    private List<LecturerEntity> lecturers;
}



/*
 * One to Many Bidirectional DepartmentEntity and LecturerEntity
 */
departmentRepository = ctx.getBean(DepartmentRepository.class);
lecturerRepository = ctx.getBean(LecturerRepository.class);
department = new DepartmentEntity("Department");
List<LecturerEntity> lecturers = new ArrayList();
lecturers.add(new LecturerEntity("Lecturer 1"));
lecturers.add(new LecturerEntity("Lecturer 2"));
department.setDepartments(lecturers);
departmentRepository.saveDepartment(department);
```

I got this in my table
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAwAm.jpg)
Why is department_id in Lecturer table null?
please help, I can't spot the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you set `department` at `LecturerEntity`?

Comment: Thank you. I forgot setDepartment in lectureEntity.